# How to trigger a iron-ajax request on a paper-button click?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, polymer

I would like `<iron-ajax>` to `POST` dynamic data from a `<textarea>` to `http://example.net` when I click a `<paper-button>` element:

```js
function get_data() {
  return {content:document.getElementById("mycontent").html()}
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Imports-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <iron-ajax
      url="//example.net"
    ></iron-ajax>
    <paper-button id="mybutton"></paper-button>
    <textarea id="mycontent"></textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I combine the [iron-ajax](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax) and [paper-button](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-button) elements to send the data to the server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to wrap your polymer elements in a tag that will register as polymer element. You can use `dom-bind` in your case.

```
<template id="t" is="dom-bind">           
    <textarea value="{{dataToPost::input}}"></textarea>
    <paper-button on-tap="postData">Post Data</paper-button>
    <iron-ajax 
    id="dataAjax" 
    method="post"
    url="data/url"
    on-response="postComplete"></iron-ajax>
</template>
```

In the script you need to call `generateReqeust` on `iron-ajax` element.

```
(function (document) {
'use strict';
document.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {

    // We have to bind the template with the model
    var t = document.querySelector('#t');
    var ajaxRequest = t.$.dataAjax;

    // make the iron-ajax call
    t.postData = function() {
      ajaxRequest.body = {
        'text': t.dataToPost;
      } 
      ajaxRequest.generateRequest();
    }

    //callback on request complete
    t.postComplete = function(){
      alert('whoa! request complete');
    }
});
})(document);
```

Working plunker for `GET`: http://plnkr.co/edit/13QJ7QFETIBg4bEiCMS7?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I want to wait a bit before I accept it to see if others come up with good solutions as well.

Comment: I just realized you are looking for `POST`. Modified my answer to post data.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and least expensive way is to just query the iron ajax element and call the method `generateRequest()`

Place this in your `on-tap` handler for paper-button...

`Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('iron-ajax').generateRequest()`

Comment: How do you send in a parameter from here?

Answer (score 0):

If you are keen on not using a `<template is="dom-bind">` (it would make it a lot easier though), you can go the plain vanilla route (i.e. no dom-bind).

```html
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Imports-->
</head>

<body>
  <iron-ajax url="//example.net"></iron-ajax>
  <paper-button id="mybutton"></paper-button>
  <textarea id="mycontent"></textarea>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
      var ironAjax = document.querySelector('iron-ajax');
      ironAjax.method = 'post';
      ironAjax.contentType = 'text/plain'; // you're just sending text
      var myButton = document.getElementById('mybutton');
      var myContent = document.getElementById('mycontent');

      myButton.addEventListener('tap', function(e) {
        var valueToSend = myContent.value;
        ironAjax.body = valueToSend;
        ironAjax.generateRequest();
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```